# how to compare data using redgate data compare tool

Tags: mysql, migration

i am trying to compare the data of two mysql databases using the redgate data compare tool for mysql. The tool identifies two databases with identical data as having different tables. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it will be work in redgate tool after creating a new project. and on Object Mapping tab ,

- select an Unmapped table or view that you want to map from the source database.
- Select the Unmapped table or view that you want to map from the target database.
- Click   Map.SQL Data Compare moves the tables or views to the upper pane.

  [image: data Comparison through redgate tool]